# Npm typescript - Git post install compile

Tags: git, typescript, npm

I've created a github repository similar to tsoa (https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa) which creates the lib repository as an Npm dependency after it has been installed. Unfortunately, it also tries to compile the other node_modules in the sibling folders and if one of them has an issue (ie react-router 4.0.30 has the type issue "Type 'location' is not generic") it interferes with the install and errors out... Is it possible to install the lib in a post-install step that doesn't attempt to install the sibling dependencies for the parent project?

Error in the installed dependencies "Npm install" step.

../@types/react-router/index.d.ts:69:13 - error TS2315: Type 'location' is not generic

Cheers

Comment: Your question does not give enough details for someone not already familiar with your setup to understand what is going on.  You might be able to get better help if you publish and post the link to a repository that reproduces the problem.

Comment: For me, the solution was to add "@types/history": "^4.7.2", to my package.json file. @types/react-router has a dependency but doesn't end up with an explicit version declared for the dependency.